# Extending the width of caption for subfigure

Tags: captions

The caption of the subfigure follows the size of the figure/table. Is it possible to stretch the width so that it does not follow the size.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{
subfigure,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\small
\centering
\subfigure[\label{fig:sub1}This is the first subfigure.]
{
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{l}
First sub figure
\end{tabular}
}
\\
\centering
\small
\subfigure[\label{fig:sub2} Second subfigure.]
{
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{l c*{2}{p{0.2cm}}}
$a$& 1 & 1  \\
$b$  & 2& 2 \\
\end{tabular} 
}
\\
\centering
\small
\subfigure[\label{fig:sub3} Third subfigure.]
{
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{l c*{2}{p{0.2cm}}}
$a$& 1 & 1  \\
$b$  & 2& 2 \\
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{\label{figure} This figure has 3 subfigures.} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This figure has 3 subfigures.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please add a minimal document showing what you're doing? There are at least two distinct methods for dealing with subfigures and it's important to know which one you're using.

Comment: This snippet doesn't show subfigures; please, edit your question, inserting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (click on the link for more information about a MWE).

Comment: Just did. Let me know if anything else is needed. It is my first time. So sorry for that.

Comment: I am so sorry I missed it. I would do it now. Had a bad day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can place the objects in a box having a prescribed width. In the code below, I've changed `subfigure` (which is an obsolete package) with `subfig` and `\subfigure` with `\subfloat`.

Watch also for *spurious spaces* that can sneak in the output, caused by unprotected end-of-lines. There's also no need to add `\small\centering` inside the `\subfloat` arguments.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\small
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:sub1}This is the first subfigure.]
{%
\makebox[.4\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}{l}
First sub figure
\end{tabular}}%
}
\\
\subfloat[\label{fig:sub2}Second subfigure.]
{%
\makebox[.4\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}{l c*{2}{p{0.2cm}}}
$a$& 1 & 1  \\
$b$  & 2& 2 \\
\end{tabular}}%
}
\\
\subfloat[\label{fig:sub3}Third subfigure.]
{%
\makebox[.4\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}{l c*{2}{p{0.2cm}}}
$a$& 1 & 1  \\
$b$  & 2& 2 \\
\end{tabular}}%
}
\caption{\label{figure} This figure has 3 subfigures.} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Egreg and Kurt, So sorry for messing up the question. Thank you so much for teaching me. Egreg : Thank you so much for helping me. Regards, Asha